# Laravel - artisan commands return InvalidArgumentException

Tags: php, laravel

Whenever I run *any* PHP artisan command (even `php artisan help`), I get:

> [InvalidArgumentException]
>   Attribute [gett] does not exist

I haven't messed with my artisan file. How do I solve this?

Comment: @Odin Doesn't work. "Nothing to install or update", and then `php artisan optimize` fails with the same exception.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this. Turns out I accidentally used `Route::gett` instead of `Route::get`. Found it by doing a global search.

Comment: Thanks! I also got "Attribute [got] does not exist" because I mistyped it.